# Уточнение значения помещения

Tags: значение

Помещением как выделенным пространством является и комната, и квартира?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да.

Помещение - здание, комната, строение для жилья, работы или вещей, товаров.

Например:

*Помещение для служащих. Жилое помещение. Помещение для экипажей. Помещение для машиниста. Сырое помещение.*

Помещение - здание, комната, где помещается кто-, что-либо.

Например:

*Жилое, служебное помещение. Подсобное помещение. Тёплое, холодное помещение. Помещение мастерской. Занимать какое-либо помещение. Оборудовать помещение для занятий кружка.*

Квартира - жилое помещение в доме, имеющее отдельный вход, обычно с кухней, передней.

В общем смысле - это то строение или его элемент, где можно разместиться.

Comment: А выделенное пространство? Вы о нем ничего не сказали. Откуда вообще взялась эта формулировка?

Comment: Да всё просто. Имеется ввиду не место на улице или в парке, а "выделенное" стенами пространство. Обычная логика)

Comment: Странная логика. В словаре этого слова (при определении помещения)  нет.  Это сочетание используется, как мне кажется,  в других случаях, например: Воздушное пространство, выделенное для местной воздушной линии.  Вот здесь оно на месте. А квартирой скромно называют "отдельное жилое помещение в доме".  Огорчает небрежность в постановке вопросов, когда приходится догадываться, что имелось в виду.  Кстати, квартира помещением вроде бы не называется, а именно об этом был вопрос.

Comment: Но ведь задающие вопрос не обязаны стилистически идеально использовать все слова. В этом вопросе мне всё ясно. А бывают такие, что вообще тёмный лес (например, про моложе/младше). Главное, чтобы была понятна суть. || Квартира — отдельное жилое помещение в доме, состоящее из одной или нескольких комнат с кухней, передней и т.п. - словарь Кузнецова. Да во всех словарях пишется, что это помещение. Хотя в разговорной речи квартиру редко так называют.

Comment: Автор задает так много вопросов, что появляется желание видет их хотя бы прилично оформленными. Всё-таки это не устная частная  беседа, а  форум "русский язык", материалы которого размещены в Сети. Поэтому  автор должен по возможности применять стилистически грамотные выражения, он здесь уже не новенький, правила знает. И всё-таки мне кажется, что ключевым выражением в его вопросе было сочетание "выделенное пространство".

Comment: Думаю, что каждый применяет по возможности. Но возможности у каждого разные. || Это не совсем форум. Это один из сайтов сети Stack Exchange. Система вопросов и ответов — вид веб-сайтов, позволяющий пользователям задать вопрос или ответить на уже заданные вопросы. Первый и самый большой сайт этой сети — о программировании. На форумах возможностей гораздо больше.

Comment: Хотите сказать, что на веб-сайте  грамотность при постановке вопроса не нужна? Ну не нужна, так не нужна.  Если никого это не волнует, я тоже не буду заморачиваться.  Меня просто эмоционально расстраивает всё некрасивое и неряшливое.  Вот в нашем районе много современных торговых центров. Внутри всё сияет и блестит, а  снаружи архитектура многих самая примитивная. Давно пора бы уж привыкнуть, но я каждый раз думаю: "Какое некрасивое здание". А рядом новенький храм: заборчики, газончики. Это очень красиво.

Comment: Грамотность желательна. Но далеко не каждый может так писать. Не каждый понимает, что фраза плохо звучит. Для этого здесь всем можно править вопросы и ответы. Самое главное - чтобы была понятна суть. На составление стилистически грамотных предложений у меня иногда уходит много времени. Часто понимаю, что плохо звучит, но иногда быстро исправить не получается. Но я это просто так не оставляю. Это хорошее дело, но далеко не самое простое.

Comment: Восприятие стилистически грамотных выражений зачастую субъективно. Я употребил "выделенное", потому что мне было важно указать на наличие ограничителей, барьеров, по которым помещение и определяется. "Выделенный" ведь не обязательно означает "отличный чем-либо от других". А "отдельный" словно бы не сообщает об обособленности так прямо и неоднозначно, как "выделенный".

Comment: У глагола выделить несколько значний,  нужно догадываться, какое вы имели в виду? ВЫДЕЛИТЬ,  1. Обособить, отделить от общего, целого; вычленить. Например, в комнате было выделенное пространство для спортивных занятий.  Очевидно, что комната и квартира - это тоже выделенное (обособленное стенами) пространство. Так о чем был вопрос?  Какие варианты предполагались, сколько их, какой вариант вы выбрали? Как ответ помог решить вашу задачу? Вот что осталось за гранью моего понимания.

Comment: А пока я этого не понимаю (возможно, другие тоже не понимают), то я вижу перед собой не имеющий смысла (или плохо сформулированный) вопрос и ответ, в котором объясняется, как в русском языке связаны понятия помещение, комната и квартира (по материалам из словаря).  Интрига вопроса от меня как-то  ускользает: получается вопрос ни о чем и ответ ни о чем. Если вы задаете много вопросов, то хотя бы редактируйте их текст, в том числе название вопроса, более ответственно. Чтобы понимали их все:  не только тот, кто вам отвечает (на уровне интуиции), но и другие участники форума.

Comment: Здание также является помещением? То есть так можно сказать о дворце (великолепное помещение) , об учебном заведении (общеобразовательное помещение) , о ресторане (помещение общественного питания), или "только строящееся помещение"?

Comment: Да. Согласно словарям здания тоже помещения. "Только строящееся помещение" - более корректно употреблять касательно того, что уже построено.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что автор вопроса не зря обозначил "выделенное пространство", его скорее интересует определение "отдельное".

***Квартира*** — **отдельное** жилое помещение в доме, ***комната*** — **отдельное** помещение в квартире. Здесь они похожи.

Но есть еще комната отдыха  в учреждении (также комната матери и ребенка), которая определяется как помещение **специального назначения** (слова "отдельная" там нет).

Также квартира обязательно определяется как (1) отдельное (2) жилое помещение, то есть помещение **для жилья**, а комната может быть помещением **для отдыха**. В этом разница между ними.